# How to set default values for DTO in nest js?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, dto

I want to set default values for a node in a DTO. So if the value for that node is not passed, a default value will be used. Although this is working, I want the node should be present, the values is optional.

```
import { IsNotEmpty, IsDefined } from "class-validator";

export class IssueSearch
{
    @IsDefined()
    search: string;

    @IsNotEmpty()
    length: number = 10;

    @IsNotEmpty()
    lastId: string = "0"
}
```

This doesn't serve my purpose. I want the url to be searched like so 
http://base-url/folder?search=value

If the value is not passed it should not throw an error.

But if the param search is not there it should throw an error.

Comment: Are you using the `transform: true` option in the ValidationPipe?

Comment: Yup ... The @IsString() decorator did the trick

Answer (score 3):

If you want to set a default value go to entity and set in the field for example in mongo db

```
export class DumpDoc extends Document {
  @Prop()
  title: string;
  
  @Prop({ default: new Date() }) //set as default
  createdAt: string;
}
```